# Supervisord removing a process after successfully running

Tags: linux, debian, php, process-management, supervisord

I have the following configuration for a process to run continuously. Apparently, it works very fine but after few hours or sometimes few minutes, the process gets terminated.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

**Supervisord Config:**

```
[program:action_consumer]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command = php /var/www/the_api/web/index.php actionCron
numprocs = 2
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=console_api
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/the_api/logs/action_consumer.log
RestartSec=3
Restart=3
WatchdogSec=3
```

**OS Info:**

Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

Log file:
The log file contains the following error:

```
FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

**Important:**

It is obvious that the process terminates too quickly, it is my requirement. I don't want to run the script in an infinite loop. Is setting `startretries` a valid solution?

Comment: Check logs in /var/www/the_api/logs/action_consumer.log file. You might get better idea. If you are not able to understand the logs, Please edit your question and post it in same.

Comment: The error log just contains the output i have printed on the script using echo. Nothing else. @Nitesh

Comment: If your service is getting terminated, logs must be getting generated somewhere. How about system logs ? Did you check the system logs ?

Comment: I managed to print supervisor.log and it contains this error:
FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly

Comment: So as per your updated question, yes, you can use startretries option.

Answer (score 0):

In case the time frame for the race condition was less than a second so setting `startretries=<number you want>`. However you can set it to a much higher value if need be. Below is an example.

```
[program:test]
startretries=10
```

Comment: So supervisord will try to restart the script 10 times in a second? Can you explain this?

Comment: No, not 10 times in a second. The number explains that supervisord will attempting to start the program before giving up and putting the process into an FATAL state. 
you can find more example "http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=startretries#program-x-section-example"

Comment: How can be the startretries unlimited?

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue was of 0 second execution time. Most of the time the scripts executes within 0 seconds, so supervisor terminates it.
I resolved this issue by adding `startsecs=0`.